# Outlook 2013 Add-In MailItem

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I created an Outlook 2013 AddIn which should read the "location" field of an E-Mail.
I achieved it to get the selected MailItem and to read the subject from it but is there
a way to read the "location" field of an Meeting E-Mail?

I hope anybody is able to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the `MailItem` object to an `AppointmentItem` object to access the `Location` property:

```
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

    ....

    Outlook.AppointmentItem app;
    Outlook.MailItem mi;
    String loc;

    .....

    app = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)mi;
    loc = app.Location;

    //  or
    loc = ((Outlook.AppointmentItem)mi).Location;
```

Comment: can anybody here help me, i have almost same requirement. I need to fetch email content and display in sharepoint webpart